# How to find which position is clicked on screen or MapField in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-maps

I am building a map application. In which I am placing several bitmap and when i click on the bitmap some event is occurring. For that I need to know at which position I have clicked on the screen on the basis of that i'll get the lat & long pair for my app... Is it possible to get the exact x,y position of the screen where we clicked? 
Or is there any other way of finding which lat and long position is clicked on the MapField ?

Answer (score 0):

You can center the map to the tapped location and get the coordinates of the tap that way:

1. Get the X and Y from the [TouchEvent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/TouchEvent.html) in your extended [MapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html)
2. Get the current center of the screen from the [getXYPoint](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html#getXYPoint%28%29) function
3. Calculate the difference and use it to move the center of the map using the [move](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html#move%28int,%20int%29) function
4. The tapped location is now the center of the screen, get the coordinates using the [getLatitude](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html#getLatitude%28%29) and [getLongitude](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html#getLongitude%28%29) functions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thnaks for the help. but the problem is i dont need this way.. My application demand is that i have several location with mapkers pointing and these markers are bitmap so whenever i click i need to get the location.